# Clear specific form elements when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery, forms, input, checkbox

Can anyone give me a basic example of how to clear specific form inputs (each with it's own unique ID) when a checkbox is unchecked? I've tried a handful of solutions but just can't quite seem to get this working reliably. I need this to only happen when the box is unchecked, which seems to be giving me issues.

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Show us some code. What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough example might be...

```
<input type='checkbox' id='clear_text' />
<input type='text' id='text_box' value='Contents' />
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#clear_text").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")){ //checks if the checkbox/this is selected or not
            $("#text_box").val(""); //empty the input value
        } else { } //nothing
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `click` (and `change`, which would probably be a better choice) events fire after the `checked` status has changed; so "if it is checked, then we know that the click will 'uncheck'" is incorrect. Also, `this.checked` works perfectly well - no need for `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Comment: Aye, I think that was my original code, I edited that out shortly after. I sort-of like the $(this).is(":checked") syntax too. It reads nicely :)

Comment: Liking the syntax doesn't mean it's any less unnecessary, though. You end up writing more code - that's creating an object and performing a function call - for zero gain.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me. The others worked as well but had conflicts with some other javascript going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the checkbox's onClick(), investigate the checkbox's value, then perform whatever action you wish, including clearing the forms. Does this meet your need?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example, to get you started. Uses jQuery 1.7.1. http://jsfiddle.net/fPKX8/

HTML:

```
<input id="in1" name="in1" value="pizza" /><br />
<input id="in2" name="in2" value="chips" /><br />
<input id="in3" name="in3" value="beer" /><br />

<input id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#check1').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#in1, #in2').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chk').live('change',function(){
     if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
       $('input').val('');              
    });
})​;​
```

here is the working fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/XjRL6/)

Comment: I had to go with another solution posted as this conflicted with some other js going on with #chk. But out of the box this worked exactly as intended. Thank you for your time!