# Clear Select Based on Uncheck using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/XjRL6/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586188/clear-specific-form-elements-when-checkbox-is-unchecked) I am able to see how you can clear a input box for a form with a check box.  My question is how do I alter the javascript to clear a select (in this case 'addbasePFO14') instead by a specific name instead of just clearing ALL input found in a form without disrupting an existing onchange event?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chk').live('change',function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
     $('input').val('');              
    });

});
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <select id="addbasePFO14" name="addbasePFO14" onchange="calculateTotal()" />
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#chk").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) $("#addbasePFO14").val(0) //assuming option with value of 0 is your default
});
```

You also have two checkboxes with ID of `chk`, ID's **must** be unique!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgs3n/

Comment: hmmm.what am I doing wrong...I updated the page to include this and its not working?  When I check or uncheck the box it keeps the select the same value:        
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">Choose # of PFO Appliances          
<select id="addbasePFO14" name="addbasePFO14" onchange="calculateTotal()"  />
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select></label> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if (this.checked) $("#addbasePFO14").val(0) //assuming option with value of 0 is your default
});
});</script>

Comment: You have to include the new `change` function, not just the `if (this.checked)` part...

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco -- Here's a demo, change the select to some value, then check the box: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgs3n/

Comment: What do you mean clear? And the syntax would be `if (!this.checked)`, or just an `else` to the existing clause.